# Counting $\bmod 2$ number of vertices of sparsely represented polyhedra

Tags: computational-complexity, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, enumerative-combinatorics, polyhedra

Given a polyhedron

$$Ax\geq b$$

is there an $NC^1$ or an $NC^2$ algorithm to count the number of vertices $\bmod2$?

Assume $A\in\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb Z^{m}$ ($m=O(n)$) and assume rows of $A$ are limited in sum to $O(1)$ (constant).

I wonder if handshaking lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) is applicable to the problem.

Comment: Could you please define an $NC^1$ algorithm? Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity) If a problem can be solved in $O(\log^i n)$ time on $poly(n)$ processors it is in $NC^i$.